# Passing methods into methods Python

Tags: python

I have a class in python. What I am trying to achieve is to pass one method into another. Say I have a method that is scanning for directories on a page and another method that opens the wordlist for which it will format all the words to pass into the method that is scanning the directories.

My issue is that the method that is formatting the words by stripping them, is not being passed into the method that is scanning directories.

```
class exampleClass:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def openWordlist(self):
        try:
            with open(wordlist, 'r') as file:
                for word in file:
                    word = word.strip()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('File does not exist')

    def scanDomain(self):
        try:
            domain = 'http://' + targetURL + '/' + word
            r = requests.get(domain)
                if r.status_code == 200:
                    print(f'[+] {domain}')
                else:
                    if isVerbose:
                        print(f'[~] {domain}')
                    if r.status_code == 200:
                        print(f'[+] {domain}')
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            print('[!] CONNECTION ERROR! Exiting...')
            sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = exampleClass()
    obj.openWordlist()
    obj.scanDomain()
```

My goal is to pass the method *openWordlist()* to the *scanDomain()* method so it gets to read that wordlist and parse each request.

Comment: Why do you mention argparse?

Comment: Sorry about that. I must of not cleared out my initial question that I have figured out.

Comment: so, you want to call the `openWordList()` function from inside the `scanDomain()` function?

Comment: Yeah, I want the functionality of openWordlist() inside scanDomain()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is what you want, but you can simply add an argument to the function that should receive the other function, and then execute the function that was passed like this:

```py
class exampleClass():

    def openWordList(self):
        print("Do something else")

    def scanDomain(self, a_function):
        print("Do something")
        a_function()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = exampleClass()
    obj.scanDomain(obj.openWordList)
```

Answer (score 0):

To call a method inside another method, you can call it using the `self` argument (which represents your class inside its methods).

```py
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        pass


    def foo(self):
        return True


    def bar(self):
        res = self.foo()
        return res
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your example how `openWordlist` and `scanDomain` are supposed to interact. I infer from the shared variable `word` that it is supposed to be shared between the two methods. A good way to do this is to make `word` an attribute of the class instance.

```
class exampleClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.words = None
        self.targetURL = ""

    def openWordlist(self, wordlist):
        try:
            with open(wordlist, 'r') as file:
                self.words = [word.strip() for word in file]
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('File does not exist')
    
    def scanDomain(self):
        for word in self.words:
            domain = 'http://' + self.targetURL + '/' + word
            try:
                r = requests.get(domain)
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                print('[!] CONNECTION ERROR! Exiting...')
                continue
            if r.status_code == 200:
                print(f'[+] {domain}')
            else:
                if isVerbose:
                    print(f'[~] {domain}')
```